# failed to look up views

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Here is my structure  like

```
app.js 
routes
   index.js 
views
   partials
   index.ejs
```

This is index.js in routes folder that is rendering the template called index.ejs form views folder

```
const  express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const path = require('path');


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, '../index'));

})


module.exports = router;
```

Error says  Failed to lookup view "layout" in views directory

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the views directory first in app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs'));
})
```